# I got a OutOfMemoryError when adding a object to an ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, out-of-memory

OUT OF MEMORY ERROR ON THE LINE THAT ADDS THE OBJECT TO THE ArrayList - LAST LINE

I want every time I click the button saveScore, the name of the first team selected from the first `spinner`, the name of the second team selected from the second `spinner`, the score from the first `editText`  and the score from the second `editText` to be the arguments of my class object.

`teamOneScore` & `teamTwoScore` are two `EditText` where I enter the score for each team selected from the spinners and `arrList` is my `ArrayList` of objects .

I have a `class` - `TeamsViewModel` with 4 members of type String:  `team1Name`, `team2Name`, `team1Score`, `team2Score`.

```
 saveScore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean resultAddTeamOneScore = addTeamOneScore(weakActivity, teamOneScore.getText().toString().trim(), teamTwoScore.getText().toString().trim());
        boolean resultAddTeamTwoScore = addTeamTwoScore(weakActivity, teamTwoScore.getText().toString().trim(),teamOneScore.getText().toString().trim());
      if (resultAddTeamOneScore && resultAddTeamTwoScore) {
          dialog.dismiss();
          }

     /** save the teams selected from the spinner */
     String selectedT1 = teamOneSpinnerSelected(teamOneSpinner);
     String selectedT2 = teamTwoSpinnerSelected(teamTwoSpinner);
     while (!selectedT1.equals(selectedT) {
        /** add to the ArrayLists of objects the teams selected and their's score*/
        arrTeam.add(new TeamsViewModel(selectedT1, teamOneScore.getText().toString().trim(), selectedT2, teamTwoScore.getText().toString().trim()));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you check, what was the size of array when it throwed this exception

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while (selectedT1 != selectedT2)
```

to

```
while (! selectedT1.equals(selectedT2))
```

The condition (selectedT1 != selectedT2) may be always true, although the two Strings have identical content, and you have an endless loop leading to the OutOfMemoryError. In Java Strings must not be compared using != or ==, always use equals().

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, but the error persists even with this change